# Ошибка синтаксиса? C++

Tags: c++

[image: Скопировал код с книги]

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int samplе[5];
    int t;
    for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) samplе[t] = t;
    
    return 0;

}
```

Пробовал сделать похожий цикл. Столкнулся с этой ошибкой, списал 1 в 1 с книги, ошибка все равно остается. я не понимаю из - за чего это и как это фиксить.

[image: скрин с книги]

Comment: ИМХО, ошибка не в этом коде. Что там у Вас еще при-include-жено?

Comment: Какие заголовочные файлы включены? Не забыли ли  `using namespace std;`, если `#include <clocale>`?

Comment: только iostream

Comment: #include <clocale> помогло, спасибо Chorkov

Comment: Build -> clear all  и  компилировать еще раз. Данный код за комментировать и  компилировать еще раз

Comment: Уберите `setlocale`. Оно делает не то, что вы думаете, что оно делает. И используется не правильно.